# Wordpress redirect to a subdirectory with permalinks

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a wordpress blog in a subdirectory at domain.com/blog. I want to access it from the main domain, without anyone seeing it is in a subdirectory. I've managed to do a transparent redirect from the domain to the directory using some help, but I can't seem to get the pretty permalinks to work. This is what I use for the redirection:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Don't apply to URLs that go to existing files or folders.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Only apply to URLs that aren't already under /blog.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/

# Rewrite all those to insert /blog.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/$1

# Redirect the root folder.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ blog/ [L]
```

And this is what I would use for permalinks if the blog wasn't in a subdirectory and there wouldn't be any redirects:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

As far as I've tried combining the two rulesets, I either get an infinite loop or a not found from wordpress.

So how can these two rulesets be merged, so that the blog could be accessed by redirecting to a subdirectory and friendly urls could be used?

Thanks

Comment: Read steps in this link: http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

Answer (score 0):

perma link is just a setting in your admin side
go to setting and look for that and change the website url
not the wordpress url!!

Comment: I meant "Pretty permalinks" or so called friendly urls. I'll update the question, thanks.